# Keycloak restrict login from one domain using user name and password

Tags: keycloak

I have configured keycloak for both identity broker and identity provider. So in the main theme I have form for user name and password and in the same page I have option for login using GMAIL. Now when user uses gmail user name like example@gmail.com and password I don't want the login to happen and also on wrong username and password I don't want to lock the account.

I am using one realm and many clients. I don't want to remove the account lock functionality as for non gmail accounts it should work as it is.

If they are going to enter gmail id I want to provide an error message stating "use login using gmail identity broker" and also the error message should be multilingual.

But they use some other non gmail account then they can login using username and password and account locking functionality should work as it is.

I am using keycloak version 19.

Comment: perhaps what you need is google account social login it will redirect users to google login page so you don't have to manage the google account policy here is the link reference https://www.keycloak.org/docs/19.0.3/server_admin/index.html#_general-idp-config

Comment: That I have already integrated. But they can use the same gmail account and password in the username and password field of keycloak and if they try to do multiple wrong attempt then the account will be locked. I cann't disable the user name and password field as this can be used for non gmail accounts